# Array of Ruby objects returning strings on each method. Why?

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

Useful additional info:  I am using the decent_exposure gem so this might be the issue - correcting the code below:

```
expose(:get_filter_tags) do
  if params[:filter_tag_names]
    filter_tag_names = Array(params[:filter_tag_names].split(" "))
    filter_tags = Array.new
    filter_tag_names.each do |f|
      t = Tag.find_by_name(f)
      filter_tags << t
    end 
  end
end
```

So, something funny happens when I call this in the view:

```
query string ?utf8=✓&filter_tag_names=test

<% get_filter_tags.each do |ft| %>
  <%= ft.name %> 
<% end %>
```

Error message: undefined method `name' for "test":String

Why is this trying to call name on a string not a Tag object?  If I put the following in the view, and have jut one filter_tag_names item

```
def getfiltertag
  Tag.find_by_name(params[:filter_tag_names]) 
end

#view
<%= getfiltertag.name %>

query string: ?utf8=✓&filter=test
```

like above then I can call name just fine, so obviously I am doing something wrong to get an array of strings instead of objects.  I just don't know what.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to change `filter_tag_names = Array(params[:filter_tags].split(" "))` to `filter_tag_names = params[:filter_tags].split(" ")`

Comment: the funny thing was the code worked if I put it in the INDEX method but not in the DECENT EXPOSURE block ... but anyway, Chuck posted a better way to do it, below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `each` returns `self` — so if you write `filter_tag_names.each`, it returns `filter_tag_names`. You could fix this by explicitly returning `filter_tags`, but more idiomatically, you could just rewrite it as:

```
expose(:get_filter_tags) do
  if params[:filter_tag_names]
    filter_tag_names = Array(params[:filter_tag_names].split(" "))
    filter_tag_names.map {|f| Tag.find_by_name(f) } 
  end
end
```

Just as an aside, this method will return `nil` if there aren't any filter tag names. You may want to do that, or you might want to return an empty collection to avoid exceptions in the calling code.

Comment: Oh gosh, as usual, within minutes StackOverflow solves a problem I've noodled on for far more hours than it was worth - but at least I learned things along the way :-) ...thanks Chuck this is exactly what I needed to do!

Comment: Thanks for introduction to decent exposure, I found http://railscasts.com/episodes/259-decent-exposure which talks about it.

Comment: Hi Rubish ..."decent_exposure" is a gem which avoids the need to pass instance variables to the view, instead creating methods via "expose" in your controller that the view can call... it's really quite nice... see Railscasts #259 or read the Asciicasts version or check the gem documentation on Rubygems

Comment: hah - you beat me to it - Google got there for you faster than I could type, I am guessing!